# Rails + Simple form radio buttons global configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Using Rails 4.2 and Simple Form gem I have some radio buttons:

```
<%= f.input :frequency, as: :radio_buttons,
            collection: NewsletterPreference.frequencies.keys,
            item_label_class: 'radio-inline',
            label_method: lambda { |item| " #{item.capitalize} " },
            input_html: {autocomplete: 'off', class: "icheck"} %>
```

Is possible to extract `item_label_class`, `label_method`, `input_html` in an initializer file ?

In the future I will only type:

```
<%= f.input :frequency, as: :radio_buttons,
            collection: NewsletterPreference.frequencies.keys %>
```

Comment: these are just options, you can not without patching simple form I think

Comment: I don't want to patch.. I would to put this configuration inside some initializer